# Rails: Count the number of activerecord queries per route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activesupport

My main idea is to count the number of ActiveRecord queries for every API hit in rails. I was looking into ActiveSupport instrumentation API. And it seems it already provides a couple of useful data.

- `view_runtime`
- `db_runtime`

I also found a couple of gems which would count the number of queries. But they add query counts in the log data.

- https://github.com/rubysamurai/query_count
- https://github.com/comboy/sql_queries_count
- https://github.com/makandra/query_diet

Ex: Below is a sample log line when I used the `query_count` gem.

```
Completed 200 OK in 140ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 54.4ms | SQL Queries: 36 (0 cached) | Allocations: 20449)
```

But instead of a log line, is it possible to expose `query_count` via ActiveSupport events, maybe as part of the payload of `process_action.action_controller`?

Comment: `query_count` gem seems to do just that already https://github.com/rubysamurai/query_count/blob/v1.1.1/lib/query_count/controller_runtime.rb#L29

Comment: Thanks, seems like it does that. It wasn't working for me due to some issues with my code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do rails endpoint instrumentation, based on my experience is to use [rails-panel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel).

It shows how long the rendering took, how long the query took and how many queries were executed.